# select distinct keys from a json column in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

a TEXT column of a SQLite database contains json values like these one:

`[{"key1":"116"},{"key2":"260"},{"key3":"123"},{"key4":"1155"},{"key4":"1507"}]`

i need a DISTINCT list of **json keys**

```
key1 1
key2 1
key3 1
key4 2
```

can i write a VIEW using only sqlite json functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [JSON1 Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) functions like `json_each()` and aggregation:

```
SELECT j.key, COUNT(*) counter
FROM (
  SELECT j.*
  FROM tablename t, json_each(col) j
  -- WHERE ...  (if you want to apply a filter in the table's rows)
) t, json_each(t.value) j  
GROUP BY j.key;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=24a639bb37a2789fd08a1def04b0dbc1)